# after deleting from firebase it appperas again in recycleview?

Tags: android, firebase

how to delete from firebase and makes update in recycleview  because after deleting it appears again .

code ->

```
FirebaseUser firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
            FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            final DatabaseReference databaseReference = firebaseDatabase.getReference(firebaseUser.getUid());
            databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    String title = checkOutMOdel.getProductcode();
                    if(dataSnapshot.exists())
                    {
                        for(DataSnapshot ds:dataSnapshot.getChildren())
                        {
                            if(title.equals(ds.child("title").getValue(String.class)))
                            {
                                //databaseReference.child()
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

After getting new response, call your `RecyclerView` adapters `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

```
adapter.setItems(list);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```